# HTML - Send email without open new windows in Outlook

Tags: javascript, html, email, outlook

I send an email to a client that contains a button that must be pressed to send a user's cofee.

Pressing the button opens a new Outlook window and then the user must click on SEND

I would like the new window not to be opened but automatically the email must be sent without any confirmation.

is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: *"email must be sent without any confirmation"* Sounds like that would conflict with security.

Comment: I know, but if you open the new window very likely the user is not able to understand that he must press SEND

Comment: Please post the code that you are using for someone to assist you. If you are simply using a `mailto` link this will naturally just execute the default email handler which would likely be opening a new email in Outlook.

Comment: @codemonkeh Yes, i use a mailto link. What can I use to achieve the desired goal?

Comment: There isn't a specific html action that will automatically send an email. I'm not sure of what exactly the purpose is, but outlook will be necessarily sandboxed for security reasons so you would either need to link to a webpage or service and use custom code to send an email (which would pop up a browser window) or write an outlook extension to be able to provide additional functionality.

If it's just a simple question perhaps you could send it as an outlook poll? that would email you a response.

Comment: @codemonkeh Thanks so much. I did not know the polls function. 
But with the poll function I can not add a button to the body of the message, right?

Comment: @DomenicoRafti I must admit i do not know of its use programmatically, it is typically displayed in the header, so, no sorry.